# bootsrap changes dropdown menu code to something too complicated

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am using this theme material design https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/ to create a codeigniter application and I have a problem with the dropdown because it changes the code from this :

```
<select class="form-control show-tic" data-live-search="true" name="idepe" id="idepe">
    <option value="1">ALDIPH Alger</option>
    <option value="2">ALTRO Skikda</option>
    <option value="3">SOTRAMO</option>
    <option value="4">ENPS Alger</option>
    <option value="5">SOTRAMEST</option>
</select>
```

to this strange code :

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control show-tic">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="idepe" title="ALTRO Skikda" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="filter-option pull-left">ALTRO Skikda</span> &nbsp;
        <span class="bs-caret">
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 368px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 132px;">
        <div class="bs-searchbox">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="max-height: 318px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 82px;">
            <li data-original-index="0" class="active"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">ALDIPH Alger                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="1" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">ALTRO Skikda                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">SOTRAMO                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="3"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">ENPS Alger                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="4"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">SOTRAMEST                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="5"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">EPTP Alger                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="6"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">SONATRO Alger                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="7"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">EPTP Constantine                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="8"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">SEROR Telmcen                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="9"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">ERTP Tebessa                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="10"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">SERA Oran                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="11"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">ETR Bejaia                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="12"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">SAPTA Alger                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="13"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">GESI-TP Alger                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="14"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">MEDITRAM Alger                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="15"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">SOTROB Oum Elbouaghi                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="16"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">ENROS                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="17"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP ADRAR                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="18"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP LAGHOUAT                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="19"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP OUM EL BOUAGHI                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="20"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP BATNA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="21"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP BEJAIA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="22"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP BISKRA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="23"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP BLIDA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="24"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP BOUIRA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="25"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP TAMENRASSET                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="26"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP TEBESSA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="27"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP TLEMCEN                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="28"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP TIZI OUZOU                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="29"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP ALGER                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="30"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP DJELFA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="31"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP JIJEL                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="32"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP SETIF                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="33"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP SKIKDA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="34"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP ANNABA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="35"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP GUELMA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="36"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP CONSTANTINE                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="37"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP MEDEA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="38"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP MOSTAGANEM                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="39"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP MSILA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="40"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP OUARGLA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="41"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP ORAN                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="42"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP EL BAYADH                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="43"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP ILLIZI                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="44"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP BORDJ BOU ARRERIDJ                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="45"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP EL OUED                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="46"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP MASCARA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="47"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP BOUMERDES                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="48"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP TAREF                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="49"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP TISSEMSSILT                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="50"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP TINDOUF                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="51"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP KHENCHELA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="52"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP SOUK AHRAS                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="53"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP TIPAZA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="54"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP MILA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="55"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP NAAMA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="56"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP AIN TEMOUCHENT                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="57"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">DTP GHARDAIA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="58"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">ADA                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="59"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">ANESRIF                    </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control show-tic" data-live-search="true" name="idepe" id="idepe" tabindex="-98">
        <option value="1">ALDIPH Alger </option>
        <option value="2">ALTRO Skikda </option>
        <option value="3">SOTRAMO </option>
        <option value="4">ENPS Alger </option>
        <option value="5">SOTRAMEST </option>

    </select>
</div>
```

Does anyone know hhow I prevent bootsrap from changing the code for the dropdown

Comment: Remove the "form-control" class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because theme material design includes custom select code for that.
If you don't want it then remove custom select code.
For custom select code like this or it's targeted on class(form-control show-tic).

```
$('select').selectpicker();
```

Also, remove bootstrap-select.js.

Comment: I have removed  bootstrap-select.js from code and that worked perfectly , thanks a lot